# Flask API works in Postman and browser but cannot be get using axios or fetch

Tags: javascript, flask

I got this Flask API

```py
@app.get("/jobs/{keyword}")
def search_jobs(keyword: str):
    # Search for jobs in Elasticsearch
    body = {
        "size": 10000,  # Adjust the size as per your requirements
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": keyword,
                "fields": ["*"]
            }
        }
    }

    result = es.search(index="jobs_index", body=body)
    hits = result["hits"]["hits"]

    jobs = []
    for hit in hits:
        job_info = hit["_source"]
        jobs.append(job_info)

    return jobs
```

I can see the result of the API in browser, also Postman:

Browser directly access
[image: Browser directly access]

Postman
[image: Postman]

My code using axios, I do try fetch but it does not work too

```
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const queryUrl = `${searchUrl}${encodeURIComponent(title)}`;
  const getJobs = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log("Start fetching data...");
      console.log(queryUrl);
      const res = await axios.get(queryUrl);
      console.log(res);
      setJobs(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      setLoading(false);
    } finally {
      console.log("End fetching data...");
      setLoading(true);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getJobs();
  }, []);
```

I got nothing when using axios:

Console output (I click the url and it work using browser)

[image: Console output]

I had also tried absolute url but still not work

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me to figure it out